# Google maps how to keep infoWindow open when marker coordinates change

Tags: swift, google-maps

I currently have a marker on the map using google map. I want to keep the infoWindow visible until the user tap elsewhere. The issue is that it work as it should when the user is coords do not change but whenever the user drive and coord change the info window disappear immediately. I would like to keep the info window there even if the marker move away from. Thank you in advance for the help

Answer (score -3):

**first make info window object**

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: "Hello World"
  });
```

**then make latlng object containing latlng and setposition of infowindow**

```
infowindow.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(19.243750,73.149095))
```

**then open on map**

```
infowindow.open(map)
```

Comment: can you convert that to swift.

Comment: sry sir,i m not familiar with swift i cannot help you with that